# Does an inequality hold as an expectation over a probability distribution?

Tags: distributions, probability-inequalities, inequality

Suppose I have to functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that
$$
f(x) \leq g(x) \quad \forall x.
$$

For a distribution $\pi(x)$ on $x$, is it necessarily true that
$$
E_\pi[f(x)] \leq E_\pi[g(x)]?
$$

My thinking is this is true due to the fact that
$$
E_\pi[f(x)] = \int f(x) \pi(x) dx \leq \int g(x) \pi(x) dx = E_\pi[g(x)],
$$
given that $\pi(x)$ is a non-negative function.

Comment: You may be interested in stochastic ordering as a way of characterizing the relative ordering of two processes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering

Answer (score 1):

$\forall x$ $f(x)\leq g(x)$ 
As $\pi(x)$ is a distribution, we have $\pi(x)\geq0$. By multiplying $\pi(x)$ to the inequality : 
 $\pi(x)f(x)\leq \pi(x)g(x)$ $\forall x$ 
if $f$ and $g$ are measurable we have:
we will use the linearity of the integral :
$\int\pi(x)f(x)\leq \int\pi(x)g(x)$    $\forall x$ 
$E_{\pi}[f(x)]\leq E_{\pi}[g(x)]$    $\forall x$

Comment: Thanks, this seems to match with my thinking. I have not taken a measure theory course, how would I go about determining whether $f$ and $g$ are measurable?

Comment: The measurability of a function is based on the concept of measurable space. In my opinion, there is no intuitive definition of measurable function. But for simplicity, make sure that they are continuous functions. **NB**: _a non continuous fonction can be a mesurable function. The contuinity ensures the measurability_

Answer (score 0):

$E(g(X))-E(f(X)) = E(g(X)-f(X))= \int (g(x)-f(x))\,\pi(x)\, dx \geq 0$ (since the integrand is everywhere non-negative).

You can generalize the argument in similar fashion.